# How to find inexistant files in the project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Context: C++ MFC project in Visual Studio 2013

I had following problem:

Whenever I started debugging, VS2013 complained that my project was out of date even if a full successful rebuild (without any warnings) had been done just before. I tracked down the problem (not without difficulties) and found out that the cause was a .h file that was present in the project but that .h file didn't exist anymore and it wasn't used by any of the .cpp files. So I removed that .h file from the project and the problem went away.

Now is there a way to check for suche orphan .h files automatically ?

IMHO VS should at least show a warning saying that the .h file doesn't exist.

Comment: Load up the `.vcxproj` XML, extract the file paths, compare with the file system.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz sure, but shouldn't this be Visual Studio's job ?

Comment: In the referenced duplicate, for VS2013 you can go to Tools, Options, Projects and Solutions, Build and Run and change build output verbosity to `Detailed`.  You get a line `Project not up to date because build input 'Header.h' is missing.`.